# Can neither being used in a nominal sentence (no verb)?

Tags: determiners, neither-nor

So I've had a debate with a friend about the sentence:

Good promotions don't expire, neither grammar.

(I know it doesn't make logical sense, this is from an ESL discount campaign, in my country, for single's day).

I said that there should be a does before grammar to be grammatically correct as a sentence. They say it is a nominal sentence so "does" can be omitted. Therefore, the sentence can still be gramatically correct.

However,  doesn't neither before a noun act as a determiner, that can be alternated with no; therefore saying "no grammar"?

Thank you for the help, this has left me awaken at 2 am wondering if it is correct or if it is wrong.

Any opinions?

Comment: I meant in formal English.

Comment: Regardless of whether you might argue it’s passable, I’d add the “does”.  I think it’s obtuse without it.

Comment: It seems to be an ad selling the services of a language school - perhaps the broken English is deliberate? Or an honest statement of the capabilities of the school's teachers?

Comment: I'm not going to lie, I think it's an honest statement of their lack of double checking the person who did the campaign.